# Data classification in Unity Catalog of Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-purview, databricks-unity-catalog

**Question**: Does [Unity Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/) in Azure Databricks have the feature of classifying assets? If so, can someone please provide links to online documentation on this feature in Unity Catalog? Please see the context below:

`Unity Catalog` is the Azure Databricks data governance solution for the Lakehouse. And [Microsoft Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/overview) is a data governance solution for on-premises, multicloud, and software-as-a-service (SaaS) data.

The [Data classification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/concept-classification) in the Microsoft Purview governance portal is a way of categorizing data assets by assigning unique `logical tags` or classes to the data assets. Classification is based on the business context of the data. For example, you might classify assets by Passport Number, Driver's License Number, Credit Card Number, SWIFT Code, Person’s Name, and so on.

When Purview scans your data storage it identifies/classifies the data assets based on the data that matches the classification (logical tags such as Passport Number, Credit Card number etc.)

When you classify data assets, you make them easier to understand, search, and govern. Classifying data assets also helps you understand the risks associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

Unity Catalog right now doesn't provide such classifications. There were roadmap presentations that included the notion of attribute classes that could be also used to classify objects and assign permissions for accessing data marked as specific attribute (attribute-based access control). But right now there is no specific timeline for that future.

Although it's now possible to use SQL to add comments on both table & column level, although it may not be very convenient.

P.S. Potentially Purview <-> Unity Catalog integration will allow use use Purview's UI to classify data in UC, but I haven't seen such integration in